Should I cache marker BitmapDescriptor in Android?
In my Android app, I am displaying 1000s of markers on Google Maps, I am caching the BitmapDescriptor of each marker.
Is it a good approach to cache Bitmap Descriptor? If yes, am I doing it correctly?
When displaying a large amount of markers, the UI kind of lags
object MarkerIconCache {
// Cache size based on typical number of unique marker types you expect
private const val CACHE_SIZE = 1000

data class MarkerKey(
    val number: String,
    val date: String
)

private val iconCache = object : LruCache<MarkerKey, BitmapDescriptor>(CACHE_SIZE) {
    override fun entryRemoved(
        evicted: Boolean,
        key: MarkerKey,
        oldValue: BitmapDescriptor,
        newValue: BitmapDescriptor?
    ) {
        // Clean up bitmap resources when removed from cache
        oldValue.let {
            if (it is BitmapDescriptor) {
                // Optional: Release any resources if needed
            }
        }
    }
}

fun clearCache() {
    iconCache.evictAll()
}

fun getMarkerIcon(context: Context, data: MapUI): BitmapDescriptor {
    // Cache key based only on color since the bitmap really only varies by color
    val key = MarkerKey(
        number = data.name,
        date = data.Date
    )
    return iconCache.get(key) ?: createRectangleMarkerBitmap2(
        context = context,
        text = data.number,
    ).also {
        iconCache.put(key, it)
    }
}

}
Usage in composable
    @Composable
fun MapMarkers(
    mapViewModel: MapVM,
) {
    val mapData by mapViewModel.markerData.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
    val context = LocalContext.current

    //getting bitmap from cache
    val markerIcons = remember(mapData) {
        mapData.associateWith { data-> getMarkerIcon(context, data) }
    }

   //this function adjust markers if they are in same place
    val adjustedMarkers = remember(mapData) { createAdjustedMarkers(mapData) }

    adjustedMarkers.forEach { (data, position) ->
        val markerState = MarkerState(position = position)
        Marker(
            state = markerState,
            icon = markerIcons[data]        )
    }
}


Caching BitmapDescriptor is generally a good approach to avoid performance issues, but ensure that you manage memory effectively, especially with a large number of unique markers. Consider batching marker additions and using clustering techniques to enhance UI responsiveness.

Could you elaborate on batching markers?

As I said, you can use clustering in your Google Map instance, check Official Document and This Stackoverflow Post
